# How to run angular controller before loading the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, dom

I have some codes within my angular controller, I'd like this codes to be run on document ready but I noticed that angular runs it as the dom is created. Even though it gives the correct output, it generates some console errors because initially the image src attribute value is null. I set the src attribute value inside my angular controller. So initially i'm getting some console errors. Is there a way to run the controller before loading of the DOM structure?

HTML :

```
<div class = "tab1 grow">
    <a href = "#/tab1" class = "tooltip">
        <img ng-src="{{ imageUrlProfile }}">
        <span>
           <strong>Profile</strong><br />
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Controller.js:

```
application.controller('app', function($rootScope, $scope) {

        $rootScope.imageUrlProfile = 'images/profile-icon.png';
        $rootScope.imageUrlWork = 'images/exp-icon.png';
        $rootScope.imageUrlEdu = 'images/edu-icon.png';
        $rootScope.imageUrlProject = 'images/project-icon.png';
        $rootScope.imageUrlContact = 'images/phone-icon.png';

});
```

Comment: `So initially i'm getting some console errors` what errors? post that too

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND' I'm getting this because page doesn't know the 'imageUrlProfile' value initially.

Comment: I have not seen a way of loading it before DOM, may be you could do that with manual bootstrapping options and associating with before DOM loaded. But do not recommend it unless really needed. Can you add the console errors and paths to image seems image path issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any bug in your code except the image `URL`.

```
$rootScope.imageUrlProfile = 'images/profile-icon.png';
```

Make sure above `URL` is correct. [Here is the plunker of your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/lOmic9Aw16bJqJGyQr9t?p=preview). In console it displays following error message.

```
GET https://run.plnkr.co/gi7myGeYUIlWJtxg/images/profile-icon.png 404 (OK)
```

If your image `URL` is correct, I think it should work.

Comment: My image is loading. But I'm getting the console error because it does not know the value of 'imageUrlProfile' during the DOM creation. And controller is executing after the DOM creation done. The above URL is correct.

Comment: I have updated the plunker, please check it again. I have added `console.log($rootScope.imageUrlProfile); ` in my plunker, Add this line to your application and post the console output. 

My plunker working properly with valid `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at configuring routes to ensure that values are available before the controller is loaded?

Something like the below snippet:

```
app.module()
   .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'view',
            controller: 'ctrl',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            resolve: {
              /// Ensure values exist here
            });
         })
```

More here: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx